# How to delete vtk objects by checking first whether they are initialized with New()?

Tags: c++, class, vtk, delete-operator

I have a project with vtk, in which a lot of vtk objects are constructed as private members. At .h files I initialize vtk objects like below:

```
vtkSmoothPolyDataFilter *m_SmoothFilter;
vtkDecimatePro *m_DecimatePro;
vtkCleanPolyData *m_CleanPolyData;
```

During runtime, some of these objects are initialized with New() command, but some of them not. Since I can't use smart pointers (due to the incapability with my UI package) I have to delete these objects at the destructor. I have to use some boolean checking system to understand whether they are initialized:

```
if(m_SmoothFilter)
   m_SmoothFilter->Delete()
if(m_DecimatePro)
   m_DecimatePro->Delete()
```

But this code excerpt doesn't detect whether the objects are initialized. How can I do this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize all of your pointers to zero or an actual object that has been created with new.  Then your C++ delete can delete without any ifs (it's ok to delete a zero pointer).  I'm not sure what your Delete() above does.

Comment: It's like a workaround. I have lots of objects and actually don't want to initialize them all to zero. I believe there must be an other way. But if there isn't, I will make use of your idea.

Comment: @EmreTurkoz: Thats not a workaround, that is the way to do it in C++. When /you/ do not initialize the pointers to anything, they will just contain garbage. There is no way to distinguish this garbage from a pointer to really allocated object.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Thanks for guidance. I will do the way described.